# how to change my hostname?

Tags: hostname

My hostname is `localhost`, reported by `hostname` command, and terminal prompt `root@localhost:~#`.

How can i change it to `mismis.com` with `mismis` alias? and what is the proper configuration.

I confused after reading some articles on web.

My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       srv345.myweb.com      srv345
178.162.231.61  janstone.mismis.com    janstone
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running the following command in a terminal.

```
sudo sysctl kernel.hostname=mismis.com
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       mismis.com mismis srv345.myweb.com srv345
178.162.231.61  janstone.mismis.com    janstone

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: where to put the `sudo sysctl kernel.hostname=mismis.com`, to run on system start-up?

Comment: you have run this command on the terminal

Comment: after editing the `kernel.domainname` and `kernel.hostname` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reboot , hostname changed. thanks for `kernel.hostname=mismis.com`

Comment: The /etc/hosts file given above is invalid. It is not permitted to have multiple lines starting with the same IP address, in this case 127.0.0.1. If multiple such lines exist then the results are, officially speaking, undefined. More pragmatically, the existence of multiple 127.0.0.1 generally indicates misconfiguration. Domain names like 'mismis.com' and 'mismis' should not normally resolve to the loopback address; but if this is really desired for some unusual reason then these domain names should be added as aliases of 'localhost' on the one and only line beginning with 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Ammar: Thanks, /etc/hosts now looks intrinsically OK. Whether it's exactly what the questioner wants, I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

The system hostname is configured in /etc/hostname. A change made to this file will take effect after reboot.

At boot time the string in /etc/hostname is loaded into the kernel using the `hostname` command. If you edit /etc/hostname then you should also set the system hostname manually using the `hostname` command.

```
sudo hostname mismis
```

Note that in Debian and Ubuntu the system hostname is the *short* hostname, not a fully qualified domain name.

If the machine has a static external IP address ADRS then this address and the hostname should appear on a line in /etc/hosts, as follows.

```
ADRS <hostname>
```

If the machine has a static fully-qualified domain name then this should appear first after the IP address on the line and the short hostname should follow it.

```
ADRS <fully-qualified-hostname> <short-hostname>
```

In the present case, assuming that the external IP address is 178.162.231.61 and the desired canonical hostname is "mismis.com", the /etc/hosts line should look like the following.

```
178.162.231.61 mismis.com mismis
```

If the machine has no static external IP address, but gets assigned addresses dynamically via DHCP, for example, then 127.0.1.1 should be used instead.

```
127.0.1.1 mismis.com mismis
```

or

```
127.0.1.1 mismis
```

In /etc/hosts, any IP address should appear on at most ONE line. On that line the first domain name that follows the IP address is the canonical hostname associated with that IP address, and any subsequent domain names are aliases for the canonical hostname.

Comment: thanks but not affected. terminal prompt and hostname command stil reporting `localhost`. but after editing kernel.hostname that works.

Comment: (1) Note that you have to run `hostname` with `sudo`. (2) The prompt in an open terminal window won't pick up the new hostname, whether it is set using `hostname` or `sysctl`. A newly opened terminal window *will* show the new hostname.

Comment: how can make it persistent ?

Comment: Edit /etc/hostname.

Comment: /etc/hostname not works, just kernel.hostname that affected after reboot.

Comment: The norm is to set the hostname in /etc/hostname. On your machine editing the contents of this file has no effect because you earlier followed the advice in the other answer to add a "kernel.hostname" line to /etc/sysctl.conf. Because of way in which the system is initialised, the contents of /etc/sysctl.conf override the contents of /etc/hostname.